# Is port channeling/LACP needed with kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, lacp

I have a 6 server setup. Each server has 4 NICs with port channeling setup to my switch for redundancy and speed. My question is simply: Can kubernetes handle this without the port channeling? Or should I stay with the port channeling?

So if I **do not** use port-channeling:

1. Can kubernetes benefit by 4 NICs speedwise when communicating between servers?
2. If one NIC breaks, will kubernetes handle all traffic over the working NICs automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter for kubernetes what kind of backend network you have: it works on top of existing OS interfaces.

Kubernetes expects you give it a reliable and fault tolerance network, hence if your hosts are communicating each other with all 4 NICs, Kubernetes will do that too.

If you don't use port channeling, then you have to avoid network loop; for example by using STP or a [bonding algorithm like round-robin or active/passive](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt). So answers are:

1. Depends on your network setup at OS level.
2. Not Kubernetes itself but the OS do the job.